# Move screen to specific line with not absolute number but the fraction of a file

Tags: vim

In vim, does anyone know how to move the screen by assigning the fraction of entire file, not the number of line?

For example, when handling a file with 100000 lines, I want to move line number 50000 by entering `0.5+(command)`.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Using Normal mode command `50%` works... Is that what you want? Only works with integer percentage numbers though...

Comment: Very simple indeed… and documented! The command is introduced in chapter 3 of the user manual: `:help 03.5` and `:help user-manual`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a Normal mode command [`{count}%`](https://vimhelp.org/motion.txt.html#N%25), which will "Go to `{count}` percentage in the file, on the first non-blank in the line, linewise." (The docs also explain how the line number is calculated for a certain percentage.)

In your example, command `50%` would take you to line 50,000.

This only works with integer percentages, since it uses the general Vim `{count}` modifier to define a percentage. Also, `0%` is not valid, as `0` does not start a count (instead, it moves to the beginning of the current line.)